# Angular 2 how to pass function with params to a child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do you properly pass a function from a parent to a child component when the function takes in parameters?

In the ngOnInit, how to scope a function like:

```
addToList(id) {
  this.store.dispatch(this.listActions.addToList(id));
}
```

ngOnInit, which is wrong right now.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this, id);
}
```

In my parent component, I have the `addToCart(id)` function.

I want to pass that function to my child component, which has a list of items, and on clicking the ADD button on an item, I want to callback addToCart(item_id) to the parent.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a function? Perhaps use an event, that seems more angular-ish

Comment: Should the id be fixed or can the child component pass an id?

Comment: is it bad to pass function?  can you give an example please

Comment: so there's a card rendered for each item, and you can click ADD to add that item_id to list.  so I want to do  a callback with the item_id

Comment: the child component will pass the item_id

Comment: See if ["Parent listens for child event"](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent) helps.

Comment: Oh okay thanks!.  But is it possible to send a calllback function with params from parent to child?

Comment: the reason i am trying to do it this way is that my parent component connects to my Store, and then I just have "dumb" components that I pass data to.

Answer (score 4):

@Maarek's answer is a good one, and is the 'right' way to do it, probably.  What I am presenting here is a simpler means of communicating specifically from the Child to the Parent.

What you proposed in the original post was to have the Parent send a callback method to the Child, so the Child can call it with data when appropriate.  To accomplish this specific task (data from Child to Parent on some action in the Child) using Events is appropriate, using the EventEmitter from inside the Child.  See this API reference which has an example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html and this Plunker I made as a demo: https://embed.plnkr.co/T1wFqVOhMXgX6NRfTuiC/

In the child, you have code like this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'item',
  template: `
    <div class="item">
      <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add</button>
      <p>{{id}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class ItemComponent {
  @Input() id: string;
  //key line here: this emitter can be bound to by parent to get notifications
  @Output() add: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  addItem() {
    //then when the button is clicked, emit events to the parent.
    this.add.emit(this.id);
  }
}
```

The Parent would call create the component like this:

`<item id="1" (add)="addToList($event)"></item>`
Where `addToList()` is a function on the Parent that does the work your callback was intended to do.  The $event is the data passed from the child (the id).

Comment: in the onClick, how would you grab some data too then?  so `(onClick)="addToList(item_id)"` ?   I am trying to do use $event but that's not really going to help me right?  The data I am getting is in {{item_id}} or {{item_name}} etc.

Comment: The on click goes to addItem(), and addItem() is a method on the Child (Item) class.  So it would have direct access to any of the Item's variables/content.  Like in the example I get the id, but it could be anything.  If you have multiple things you want to send you can bundle them into an object:

    addItem() {
      let event = { "id": this.item_id, "name": this.item_name };
      this.add.emit(event);
    }

Then on the Parent:

    <item id="1" (add)="addToList($event)"></item>
    ...
    addTooList(event) {
        let id = event.id;
        let name = event.name;
    }

Comment: ah.  i mean something like this, in which my component renders  out the items based on the array i pass it, but each item has a button.  on click I want to send only that particular item_id?  `<button class="btn btn-highlight btn-sm" (click)="handleAddToList()">Add <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>`

Comment: nvm figured it out hehe :D

Comment: The question is how to pass a function from parent to child but the answer is from child to parent. So that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question asked was to pass a function from the parent to the child.  The purpose of passing the function from the parent to the child was to pass data from the child to the parent.  So my answer was to address the underlying issue (data from child to the parent) rather than get caught in particular solution the OP had proposed.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot of detail here, but from what I'm gathering I think what you will want is an injectable service (demonstrated here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) to handle the data objects being shared between the components. Rather than type a bunch of code in here (which is better shown at that page in the tutorial) I'll describe what I think you're trying to do and how I'd go about doing it.

The entire store data model can be handled via a service (store.service.ts maybe). Which will have your CRUD functions exposed for the different properties of the store model. The list you are adding to here should have a public getter that returns an observable of the list in the service as well as a public function for adding and deleting from the list. Something like this:

```
@Injectable
export class StoreService {
  private _storeList:BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);

  /*I'm sure the store has other properties, set them up here. I'd suggest
    breaking any arrays out of the general object (unless you want to use
    pipes which are awesome but keeping it simple here) but if the store has
    a lot of general properties (name, address, whatever) they can be stored 
    in a single BehaviorSubject of type any.
  */

  constructor(){}

  get StoreList() { return this._storeList.asObservable() }

  public addToList(id) {
      let curVal = this._storeList.getValue();
      curVal.push(id);
      this._storeList.next(curVal);
  }

}
```

You would then inject this service into the constructor of both the parent and the child `constructor(private _storeService:StoreService){}` (and any other components that need it). The child could then subscribe to the list: `get List() { return this._storeService.StoreList }` and the parent can call the add function to add to the list. One thing to note, when you add this to your template as an *ngFor, make sure to pass the value through the async pipe. `*ngFor="List | async"` or your may tear your hair out trying to figure out why you're getting errors.

This article helped me a lot with this as well (although I might suggest avoiding immutable at first until you're comfortable with Angular 2 completely): http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Comment: Reading the comments above (that weren't there when I wrote this) now it looks like I wasn't seeing what your were trying to do. I'm still going to leave this here since it may yet be useful to you though.

Comment: thanks.  this is a lot of help.  however let me update my question to explain more detail!

Comment: I've actually run my head into this same kind of problem in the past few weeks, but I don't recall what I ended up doing. I'll watch for the details and see if I can find it in my codebase.

Comment: I don't really like the emit for things like this, because it feels "easier" to keep the logic in the parent, and just pass it to the children so they can just do callbacks.  I want to keep the childs without any logic, just render the stuff I send it.

Comment: Would an `@Output` eventEmitter (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Output-var.html) on the child do what you are looking to do? If the parent component isn't dynamically generating the function and you want it firing the addToCart function you could add an an `@Output` to the child and do something similar to this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent

Comment: Ahh I see....if you're trying to avoid emitting then I may be stumped on this one.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but have you tried using an @Input on the child component and binding it in the parent to the function you're wanting to callback using the [] binding syntax in the template?